# Technical term for aural proficiency in a language

Tags: proficiency, listening

I have encountered several individuals in the past who have a certain level of proficiency and understanding in listening to a certain language, but are on the whole unable to create and speak/write in that same language.

Often times, these individuals grew up in an environment where said language was spoken and used-- and as a consequence learned to understand the tongue-- but communicated outside of the home using an altogether different language.

I understand that reproducing a language on your own is entirely different from understanding, or translating something spoken to you, but have always been curious if this is a more widely documented phenomena regarding language learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR Passive speaker**

---

You've probably seen something like this before,

```
+-----------------+-----------+------------+
| LANGUAGE SKILLS | RECEPTIVE | PRODUCTIVE |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+
|                 |           |            |
| Auditory        | Listening | Speaking   |
|                 |           |            |
| Textual         | Reading   | Writing    |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+
```

representing the four major areas of language learning (listening, speaking, reading, writing) and how they relate to each other. Receptive (more passive) skills are those involving language *experienced* (by the learner), and productive (more active) skills are those involving language *expressed* (by others).

Receptive skill proficiency naturally precedes productive skill proficiency because

1. Well, the only way to learn new words is through a receptive method (unless you're making up words), so since they enter the vocabulary through a receptive method, it makes sense that comprehension would naturally be strongest there.
2. When reading or listening, words are almost always in a specific context, and meaning can be much easier derived from it, as opposed to when attempting to *recall* a word, when context (aside from experience with the word) is not available.

Proficiency in receptive areas can be called **receptive (language) competency** or **passive knowledge**, and those exhibiting this characteristic are called [**passive speakers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_speakers_(language)):

> A passive speaker (also referred to as a receptive bilingual or passive bilingual) is someone who has had enough exposure to a language in childhood to have a native-like comprehension of it, but has little or no active command of it.

Note: The term "passive speaker" also includes *reading comprehension*.

---

[Here's another useful link on passive vs active vocabulary.](https://eastasiastudent.net/study/active-passive-vocabulary/)